# AlaSQL User Defined Functions with Parameters

Tags: javascript, alasql

I am new to AlaSQL:

```
alasql('CREATE TABLE cnames(domain STRING, cname STRING)');
alasql('CREATE TABLE domains(domain STRING, ip_addr STRING)');

alasql('INSERT INTO domains VALUES ("fred.com.au","192.168.0.1")');
alasql('INSERT INTO cnames VALUES ("www.fred.com.au","fred.com.au")');
alasql('INSERT INTO cnames VALUES ("mail.fred.com.au","www.fred.com.au")');

alasql.fn.getCname = function(domainName) {
  console.log('domainName ', domainName);
    return alasql('SELECT cname FROM cnames WHERE domain = ?',[domainName]);

}

var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM cnames WHERE getCname("www.fred.com.au")');    
document.getElementById('res').textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
```

I have a JSFiddle of the above here: https://jsfiddle.net/u4drqxaw/

The items I am having issues with are:

1) I realise that I am doing something wrong as my `getCname` function is being called twice because of my `SELECT * FROM cnames WHERE getCname("www.fred.com.au")`

In alaSQL, how can I just call my the function `alasql.fn.getCname` with parameter, i.e. something like:

```
var res = alasql('getCname("www.fred.com.au")');
```

2) Once I have the solution to my Q1, how do I reference the parameter passed into the function so that I can use it within the query, i.e. `[domainName]` ?

The end result is that I want to be able to call my user defined alaSQL function with the parameter of `www.fred.com.au` which in turn should just return me the one record from my cnames table for this cnames.domain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this going and have updated my JSFiddle to reflect my required solution.

See here:

```
alasql('CREATE TABLE cnames(domain STRING, cname STRING)');
alasql('CREATE TABLE domains(domain STRING, ip_addr STRING)');

alasql('INSERT INTO domains VALUES ("fred.com.au","192.168.0.1")');
alasql('INSERT INTO domains VALUES ("barney.com.au","192.168.2.3")');
alasql('INSERT INTO domains VALUES ("mail1.fred.com.au","192.168.9.9")');
alasql('INSERT INTO cnames VALUES ("www.fred.com.au","fred.com.au")');
alasql('INSERT INTO cnames VALUES ("mail.fred.com.au","www.fred.com.au")');
alasql('INSERT INTO cnames VALUES ("fred.com.au","barney.com.au")');

alasql.fn.getCname = function(domainName) {
    return alasql('SELECT cname FROM cnames WHERE domain = ?',[domainName]);  
}

alasql.fn.processCname = function(cnameVal) {
    return alasql('SELECT getCname(?) [cname]',[cnameVal]);
}

alasql.fn.domainInfo = function(theDomain, theCname) {
    return alasql('SELECT domain, ip_addr, "'+theCname+'" [cname] FROM domains WHERE domain = ?',[theDomain]);  
}

let rec = alasql('SELECT getCname("mail.fred.com.au") [cname]');
let initialLength = rec[0]["cname"].length;

if (initialLength > 0) {
  let cnameValue = rec[0]["cname"][0].cname;
  let found = true;
  while (found) { 
    rec = alasql('SELECT getCname(?) [cname]',[cnameValue]);
    let recLength = rec[0]["cname"].length;
    if (recLength > 0) {
      cnameValue = rec[0]["cname"][0].cname;
    } else {
      found = false;
    }
  }

    let res = alasql('SELECT domainInfo(?,?) [result]',[cnameValue,cnameValue]);
    document.getElementById('res').textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
} else {
        let res = alasql('SELECT domainInfo("mail.fred.com.au", "") [result]');
        document.getElementById('res').textContent = JSON.stringify(res);
}
```

[JSFiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/96gwdyn8/9/)